# Find a document with Doctrine ODM with equals condition on nested array of objects

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2, query-builder, doctrine-odm

I got this kind of document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ad5c3b9a703a3c088b4567"),
    "hard" : 750,
    "coordinates" : {
        "x" : 0.2388169910939489,
        "y" : 0.7996551291084174
    },
    "indicator" : 500,

    "networkIdList" : {
        "networkIdData" : [ 
            {
                "networkId" : "abc123",
                "type" : "SomeNetwork"
            },
            {
                "networkId" : "123asdf",
                "type" : "AnotherNetWork"
            },
            {
                "networkId" : "abc123",
                "type" : "OneMoreNetwork"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I need to perform a query to find the document that have "networkId" = "abc123" AND "type" = "SomeNetwork".

I have tried With this instruction:

```
$this->documentManager->createQueryBuilder('Mydocument')                                    ->field('networkIdList.networkIdData.$.networkGamingId')->equals('abc123')                  ->field('networkIdList.networkIdData.$.type')->equals('')
->getQuery()
->execute());
```

But the cursor return no data.

I also try with

```
->where("function() {return this.networkIdList.networkIdData.$.networkGamingId == 'abc123'}")
```

but in this case i got an error that says the Object $ has no propierties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I need to perform a query to find the document that have "networkId" = "abc123" AND "type" = "SomeNetwork"

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Foo')
         ->field('networkIdList.networkIdData.networkId')->equals('abc123')
         ->field('networkIdList.networkIdData.type')->equals('SomeNetwork');
```

Comment: This solved my issue, when i try this for the first time, i was running out of memory, but that was caused by another instruction in my script